# C# Error on List.Find

Tags: c#, .net

I have I list of textboxes and I'm trying to Find a specific textbox inside with the following code. (using .net 2.0)

```
List<TextBox> t = new List<TextBox>();
TextBox textboxMax = t.Find(i => i.Tag.ToString().Contains(textbox.Tag + "Max"));
```

It underlines me the => end I get an error invalid expression. As I know this is the way to search in a list are the lambda expressions and from some examples all of them contained the => expression. Any ideas what is going wrong ?.

Comment: What C# version are you using? Lambdas were introduced in version 3.0.

Comment: Just curious, but if you already know that one of the textboxes has a tag called Max, shouldn't you already know the _name_ of the textbox as well? If so, wouldn't it be easier to just get the instance by name rather than trying to search the control list for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lambda expressions are only supported in .NET 3.0 and above. In .NET 2.0, you can use an anonymous delegate for this purpose.

```
TextBox textboxMax = t.Find(delegate(TextBox i) { return i.Tag.ToString().Contains(textbox.Tag + "Max"); });
```

Answer (score 4):

C# 2.0 doesn't have lambdas. You could use anonymous delegate syntax:

```
TextBox textboxMax = t.Find(delegate (TextBox i) 
{ 
    return i.Tag.ToString().Contains(textbox.Tag + "Max"); 
});
```